# wireshark is not capturing packets on lan which are sent via mobile phones or tablets

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am using wireshark to capture packets. it only captures packets from other laptops or computers in promiscuous mode, but it does not capture packets from android devices or phones, tablets, etc. can anyone please tell any other software for capturing and analyzing packets sent from mobile phones?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the PC running Wireshark to the same wireless node as the phones/laptops over Wi-Fi, then you should see packets.

Comment: well, my pc is connected to the same lan network in which my android tablet is connected, but I don't see any packets or traffic that I browse in my tab on wireshark

Comment: It needs to be connected to the same node(Wifi device) as the devices you wish to look at. If you connect it to the same LAN all packets are not necessarily captured.

Comment: yes they are connected to the same node i.e. my wifi modem, but again Im unable to see packets that are sent from my tablet on wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is exactly what you need but you need to be on the same network without anything like 'wireless isolation' enabled. Normally I setup an ad hoc connection on the machine I am capturing from and connect the device directly to that.